# Android 6.0: Phone remains unlocked after boot?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I've a screen unlock password set on my Nexus 6P and the password also gets prompted before the device is booted. However, after the device is booted, the phone is unlocked: that is, I'm sent to the launcher.

I regard this as a minor security risk since there's some time after entering the password (before the device is booted) and before the device has been fully booted.

Anyone face something similar? Anyone have a solution?